# How do I tell which process is chown'ing my file?

Tags: files

I have a file that should be owned by a regular user being chown'ed to root by something approximately every 4 and 20 minutes past the hour.  How can I tell what is doing this?

There doesn't seem to be anything in /etc/crontab or root's crontab at 4/20 minutes that would do this...

To workaround this problem, I've been doing this:

```
while true; do 
  inotifywait -e attrib /path/to/file
  chown userid:usergroup /path/to/file
done
```

But I'd really like to know how to figure out what process is instantaneously modifying the file and fix this once and for all

Comment: It's also possible something is replacing the file (i.e. deleting it and creating a new one in its place). If you use `ls -li` to show the file's inode number, does that change (indicating it's actually a different file) when it gets changed?

Comment: Similar (you can easily adapt the answer): [monitor file permission changes](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/150241)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [enable process accounting](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/accton.8.html) you will be able to use [`lastcomm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lastcomm.1.html) to identify processes that have executed [`chown`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html)

On Debian (and possibly other `deb`-based systems) the package containing the `accton` command is `acct`

```
apt install acct
accton on

touch file
chown roaima file    # Failed, but no matter

lastcomm chown
chown        roaima    pts/0    0.00 secs Sat Nov  6 10:12
```

Comment: The `--pid` option would be useful to show the parent pid as well. This approach will however only work if the ownership is being changed by the `chmod` binary; Stéphane’s linked solution tracks calls to the relevant syscalls, so it will work regardless of which binary is used.

Comment: Thanks all for answering my question -- yourself and  
Stéphane for helping me figure out what was doing the chown...

As it turns out, Gordon was right about the file not actually being chown'd and being replaced instead.  His tips led me to find the actual cause.  Thanks!